# How to configure java rome fetcher for use with a proxy and authentication

Tags: java, rss, rome

I'm trying to use java rome-fetcher to acquire rss feeds for processing. Everything works fine when I have direct internet access.

However, I need to be able to run my application behind a proxy server.

I have been unable to figure out how this can be done with rome-fetcher.

I am aware of the jvm

`System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxy);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);`

hack, but that is not an option for reasons I don't really want to explain.

With HttpClient you typically do something like this.

`DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost proxyTarget = new HttpHost("proxy.server.com", 4444);
client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxyTarget);`

Does anyone how to assign proxy settings, and authentication credentials for that matter, to rome-fetcher?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` is the only option to use **http proxy** for Rome for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Because the System.setProperty(...) is the only proxy option for rome-fetcher I ended up downloading a copy of the rome-fetcher source and made modifications to the underlying http client so it can handle different proxy configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Fetcher was deprecated in version 1.6 of Rome and will be removed in version 2.0:

https://github.com/rometools/rome/issues/276

One of the reasons given is that the user doesn't have full control over the underlying HTTP connection -- an example being the inability to specify a proxy. Directly using Apache HttpClient is suggested instead.